# GROUP BY performance

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT HOUR(datetime) as Hour, COUNT(*) as hits, SUM(clicks) 
FROM visitors_log_table 
WHERE datetime >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY Hour 
WITH ROLLUP
```

It works fine. But I don't need  `GROUP BY` for the `clicks` column.
I only need the `WITH ROLLUP` result for it.

This query is just an example. In my query I have many more columns like the `clicks` column where I don't need a `GROUP BY`.

My table is very, very large, so performance is important. The `datetime` column is indexed.
So should I do a seperate query, or should I leave it like that, or...?

Comment: I think that I see what you're driving at, but could you post (at [SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)) DDL for your visitors_log_table and some DML with sample data, the result you desire and the logic you used to obtain that result. It would help clarify your request.

Comment: Is performance of this query actually an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/67930/design-of-an-application-log-database/68361#68361) - you could take a similar query and use MySQL events (see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-mysql-events/)) to add rows to an aggregation table on an hourly basis - say at 5 minutes past the hour, perform a query for the previous hour's clicks and hits - that way you'd only be querying an hour at a time and I presume that the performance would be OK for a small subset of your results. Since it's logging you're doing, any logged data isn't going to change, so querying 1 hour at a time makes sense - i.e. (pseudocode)

```
SELECT HOUR<my_time_field> AS Hour, <my_aggregates> 
FROM <my_table> 
WHERE MyTime 
BETWEEN (Now - 65mins) AND (Now-5mins);
GROUP BY Hour
```

Something like that might be a solution to your issue?